# Can we assign dates to the UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uidatepicker

I have an array of dates ,is it possible to assign those dates as datasourse of the UIDatePicker in  an iphone app ? if so, how can i do that? Thanx in advance!

Comment: `UIDatePicker` does not have a data source; what would you like to assign?

Comment: If you have array of dates u can use normal UIPickerView. You can also create section in that if you wants

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight Ya i know that, is there any way to populate those dates from our own array of dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIDatePicker does not have a data source.Use `UIPickerView` for the purpose ,load your dates and Bang.good to go

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
   NSString * str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[yourDateArray objectAtIndex:0]];

   yourDatePicker.date = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] dateFromString:str];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant use a UIDatePicker like that. You can make use of UIPickerView.

Answer (score 0):

use normal UIPickerView, instead of UIDatePickerView. You can create sections in UIPickerView
You will have to implement the datasource and the delegate.

once you press a button, set an array pointer to the appropriate array.

than call [thePicker reloadAllComponents];

```
-(IBAction) usButtonPressed:(id)sender{
           self.inputArray = self.usArray;
            [self.thePicker reloadAllComponents];
        }

       -(IBAction) mexicoButtonPressed:(id)sender{
          self.inputArray = self.mexicoArray;
           [self.thePicker reloadAllComponents];
         }
```

the datasource methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.inputArray count];
}
```

the delegate methods:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.inputArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```